# How to show onto condition for the regular point

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, optimization

[image]

Here's the definition of a regular point form the book "Optimization by Vector Space Methods by David G.Luenberger". I was wondering how to show the onto condition here. Can I interpret it as folows:

$$\text{ For all } g \in Y \text{ , there exists } f \in X \text{ such that } T'(x_0)(f)=g $$
?

Is there a better way to show the onto condition without the definition above?

Comment: onto means surjective, so your interpretation is correct.

Comment: But, for the functional spaces, I had a hard time showing the onto definition.Is there another easy way to show the onto or any other examples?